# MacOS screen share not working

Tags: macos, network, wifi, ethernet, screen-sharing

I have a Mac Mini M1 running Ventura. On the same LAN I have an older Intel iMac running Monterey.

In the past I have routinely connected from the Mac Mini to the iMac using Screen Share. For the last few days or so I can’t.

I have tried restarting both machines and that hasn’t helped.

The iMac has two network connections: one on ethernet and the other on WiFi. Both are working and respond to LAN scans and to ping.

I can successfully connect to the iMac if I select the IP address of the WiFi connection, but not the ethernet connection, as I have done in the past. I can also connect to the iMac using a third party program called Jump Desktop and connecting via Bonjour.

What would cause my iMac to be unavailable to screen share via the ethernet connection?

Comment: If you disable WiFi on the iMac (and maybe restart), does it work with the Ethernet IP?

Comment: Is it possible that Screen Sharing has been disabled in System Preferences/System Settings after an update? Check Screen Sharing settings in `System Preferences`>`Sharing`>`Screen Sharing`. If it's been toggled off then toggle it on and see if that helps? Make sure you check both Macs

Comment: @nohillside I’ve just tried it. Turning off WiFi doesn’t make screen sharing work on Ethernet.

Comment: @AVelj On my system, it tells me that Screen Sharing is managed by Remote Management. There, it says that Screen Sharing is turned on. That’s not surprising, as it works with Wifi.